# Global quotient orbifold

Tags: finite-groups, manifolds, orbifolds

I am a little bit confused about global quotient orbifolds. I dont know if there are any conditions that must be satisfied by the group action on the manifold. This is what I thought could be done:

Let $M$ be a smooth $n$-manifold an $G$ a finite group acting on it smoothly. Let us put an obifold structure on $X:=M/G$. A global uniformizing system for $X$ is given by $(M,G,\pi)$ where $\pi\colon M\rightarrow M/G$ is the natural projection map.

Now we can make uniformizing systems for neighborhoods of points in $X$. For any point $x\in X$, choose a connected open neighborhood of $x$. Choose a connected component of $\pi^{-1}(U_x)$, say $\tilde{U}_x$, and let $\tilde{G}_x$ be the subgroup of $G$ such that $\tilde{G}_x\cdot\tilde{U}_x\subset \tilde{U}_x$. Then $(\tilde{U}_x,\tilde{G}_x,\pi|_{\tilde{U}_x})$ is a uniformizing system for $U_x$.

My question is whether this description is complete.

Comment: No, this does not work. The group $G_x$ needs to fix $m\in M$, $m\in \pi^{-1}(x)$. Think of your construction in the case $U=X$ ($X$ is connected).

Comment: @MoisheCohen I don't understand why $G_x$ needs to fix $m\in\pi^{-1}(x)$. I am using the appendix A of the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0103156 which gives an introduction to orbifolds. There we have a lemma 4.1.1 which says that this uniformizing system I constructed is really a good one. Maybe I misunderstood something. I would be grateful if you want to elaborate.

Comment: I see, they are using a definition of orbifold which I do not recognize. Usually, one requires $\tilde{U}_x$ to be open subsets in $R^n$ and the  group actions to be linear; one also requires a maximal atlas or, at least, the collection of open sets which is a basis of topology. This forces the local structure groups at $x$ to fix the preimages of $x$ once the chart is small enough (there will be exactly one preimage in this case).